# C++ STL Vector Sorting - corrupting & zeroing out

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector, corruption

The programme that I am developing is aimed to process very large amounts of data and generate at least 2^34 boolean data. These data statically generated & cleared throughout the programme run (only a portion is sorted at each instance) and finally a vector of minimum 2^21 rows of statistical data is passed to the final stage for further processing.

However, the STL Sorting fails for some input data. After Sorting finishes its process, some of the vector rows will be zeroed out or corrupted. It seems the only option that I have is to try to hard-code a hybrid Quicksort/Insertion sort algorithm.

I appreciate if you project your thoughts. Cheers.

---

Data Structure of data for the final stage:

```
struct statisticalValues{
    unsigned long long id;      //index id
    unsigned int col_Sum;       //Sum: total number of 1s for each combination
    unsigned int col_Relevancy; //Relevancy = total number of 1s produced by (Comb AND Rel)
    float col_Sensitivity;      //Sensitivity= Relevancy / X
    float col_Precision;        //Precision= Relevancy / Sum
};
extern vector<statisticalValues> statistics;
```

Calling STL Sort:

```
sort(statistics.begin(), statistics.end(), BySensitivity());
```

The comparison criteria:

```
#define EPSILON 0.0001 // user-defined tolerance for equality of floating-point numbers
struct BySensitivity {
    bool operator()(statisticalValues const &a, statisticalValues const &b) const {
        float sensitivityDif = b.col_Sensitivity - a.col_Sensitivity;

        if((sensitivityDif < EPSILON) && (sensitivityDif > -EPSILON)){
            return ((b.col_Precision - a.col_Precision) < EPSILON);
        }else{
            return (sensitivityDif < -EPSILON);
        }
    }
};
```

The rows of the sample data that will be corrupted (in no particular order):

```
id,col_Sum,col_Relevancy,col_Sensitivity,col_Precision
1568676,5353,3696,94.166,69.045
1770228,5353,3696,94.166,69.045
2040533,5353,3696,94.166,69.045
2053376,5353,3696,94.166,69.045
1231712,4668,3425,87.261,73.372
1946656,4668,3425,87.261,73.372
1948021,4668,3425,87.261,73.372
```

After corrupting & zeroing out by STL Sorting:

```
id,col_Sensitivity,col_Precision
10540996614775448722,5.8399e-34,5.8399e-34
8589934369,0.0000,0.0000
0,0.0000,0.0000
0,0.0000,0.0000
0,0.0000,0.0000
0,0.0000,0.0000
0,0.0000,0.0000
```

---

---

After implementing suggested modifications:

The comparison criteria:

```
struct BySensitivity {
    bool operator()(statisticalValues const &a, statisticalValues const &b) const {
        float sensitivityDif = b.col_Sensitivity - a.col_Sensitivity;

        if((sensitivityDif <= EPSILON) && (sensitivityDif >= -EPSILON)){
            return ((b.col_Precision - a.col_Precision) < -EPSILON);
        }else{
            return (sensitivityDif < -EPSILON);
        }
    }
};
```

Thnaks to @Mark-B, @btilly, @David-Thornley, @sth & @Daniel-Gallagher

Comment: Where is the vector created and how is it passed around in your program?

Comment: Do you get corruption when you use `stable_sort`?

Comment: There is absolutely no code shown that uses the word `vector`.  Please show the definition of `statistics` and  how some sample values are added.  Then, show how you are printing your results.  We might be able to help then.

Comment: Maybe not the problem, but it looks like if you use `BySentitivity` to compare a value to itself, it will claim that the value is smaller than itself. It shouldn't do that and you probably want ` ((b.col_Precision - a.col_Precision) < -EPSILON)` in the first case of the `if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparator doesn't implement strict weak ordering. For example two items `A` and `B` with equal `col_Sensitivity` and `col_Precision`, both `A` < `B` and `B` < `A` are true. As you can imagine, trying to sort with a sort function that doesn't actually provide an ordering can produce undefined behavior.

Thanks to (and quoting) @David Thornley for the standard reference:

> Standard, part of 25.3/3: "For the
>   algorithms to work correctly, comp has
>   to induce a strict weak ordering on
>   the values." This means that not
>   having a strict weak ordering is
>   undefined (the Standard says nothing).

I think in this case you just want to remove all the epsilon checks completely:

```
struct BySensitivity {
bool operator()(statisticalValues const &a, statisticalValues const &b) const {
    float sensitivityDif = b.col_Sensitivity - a.col_Sensitivity;

    if(sensitivityDif == 0.0)){
        return ((b.col_Precision - a.col_Precision) < 0.0);
    }else{
        return (sensitivityDif < 0.0);
    }
}};
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have to run it tonight to see the outcomes. Thanks again.

Comment: Standard, part of 25.3/3:  "For the algorithms to work correctly, `comp` has to induce a strict weak ordering on the values."  This means that not having a strict weak ordering is undefined (the Standard says nothing).  The definition of a strict weak ordering is in 25.3/4:  basically irreflexivity and transitivity.  If `A < B` and `B < A`, transitivity give us `A < A`, which violates irreflexitivity.

Comment: Thanks David, great referencing.

Answer (score 4):

The STL sort can corrupt data if the comparison operator can produce inconsistent results, such as x < y < z < x.

Your comparison operator can produce inconsistent results.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and consideration. #btilly, I think you could be right. I have to run it tonight to see the outcomes. Thanks  again.